# md-slider, como saber quando foi finalizado?

Tags: angularjs, angular-module

Tenho este *slider*:

```html
<md-slider step="5" min="15" max="120" ng-model="tempo" aria-label="red" id="red-slider" class="">
</md-slider>
```

Não consegui uma forma legal de saber quando o user altera o slider, trabalhei desta maneira:

```
$scope.tempo = 25;
$scope.tempo_final = '15 Min';

$scope.$watch(
    function(tempo) {
        console.log($scope.tempo);
    }
);
```

Mas o retorno desta função não é interessante, ainda mais que vou jogar este valor em banco, sendo assim teria alguma forma de saber quando este *slider* for alterado?

Uso o **AngularJS v1.3.15** caso indicar uma outra versão para este método, posso alterar.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca testei com o Angular Material, mas se a lógica for a mesma, você pode usar um `ng-blur` ou `ng-change`. Ambos executam uma função após interação do usuário com o campo.

A diferença é que o `ng-blur` é executado após uma interação com o campo e o `ng-change` é executado quando o valor do campo é modificado. Ambos podem chamar uma função dentro do seu `controller`, da seguinte maneira:

```
<md-slider step="5" min="15" max="120" ng-model="tempo" aria-label="red" id="red-slider" class="" ng-blur="minhaFunc(tempo)">
</md-slider>
```

ou

```
<md-slider step="5" min="15" max="120" ng-model="tempo" aria-label="red" id="red-slider" class="" ng-change="minhaFunc(tempo)">
</md-slider>
```

E no seu controller:

```
$scope.minhaFunc = function(tempo) {
    console.log(tempo);
};
```

Espero que ajude.

#### Editado:

Dê uma olhada nesse `codepen` que extrai diretamente do AngularMaterial e apenas adicionei a função do `ng-change`, ele funcionou normalmente. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPbzRV

Altere o slider e veja que novo valor vai ser escrito em cima dele.

Comment: Já testei desta maneira, ele não chama o método ng-change :(

Comment: Nem com o blur?

Comment: Tambem não aceita.

Comment: Tem que ver então como o Material lida com esse tipo de interação. Mas qual o retorno do $watch que você obteve?

Comment: @Shelon atualizei minha resposta, veja o exemplo direto do AngularMaterial, ele está funcionando.

Comment: Neste exemplo se eu remover o change e printar direto o ng-model tempo a ação vai ser a mesma.

Não utilizei o watch pois ele fica acompanhando cada movimento do slider, ou seja quando altero do numero 20 ao 150 ele faz 130 ações teoricamente, sendo assim não é viável para a aplicação que estou tentando fazer.
Preciso apenas que ele mostre o valor final, quando o user terminou a interação com o Objeto, no DragAnd.

Comment: Sim sim, imaginei. Mas você viu que eu atualizei a resposta? Ali ele está funcionando. Deve haver algo no seu código bloqueando o ng-change, ou você não setou direito. Já verificou ali?

Comment: Sim, mas neste exemplo ele manda toda vez que o número é alterado uma requisição, ou seja enquanto fico arrastando o slider, ele via enviando para o minhaFunc o numero que é passado no slider.
Eu preciso que so envie quando eu parar o slider, não quando eu estiver alterando ele.

Comment: @Shelon Mude para `ng-blur`, veja: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obgVMG